# Delete lines between 2 strings

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed, awk

I am to delete all stings from starting of file to a certain point using anything, sed, Grep, awk in shell

INPUT

```
sCSISmart20 TRAP-TYPE                                  
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                  
    DESCRIPTION                                          
    "Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"                           
    --#TYPE "Aspi: unable to read the database file"                                 
    --#SUMMARY "ASPI: unable to read the file, server hard disk may have problems"                                     
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                                 
    --#SEVERITY WARNING                                         
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                                                    
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                                          
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                                                      
    --#HELPTAG 124                         
::=  124                                                                                            

sCSISmart21 TRAP-TYPE                                     
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                
    DESCRIPTION                                                      
    "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                                  
    --#TYPE "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                          
    --#SUMMARY "ASPI: database file is corrupted"                                              
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                                                             
    --#SEVERITY WARNING                   
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                           
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                              
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                        
    --#HELPTAG 125
::=  125                

sCSISmart12 TRAP-TYPE                                                
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                        
    VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber, cycScsiTargetID, cycLun, cycVendor, cycProduct, cycSenseInfo}                                                       
    DESCRIPTION                           
    "The HostAdapter# %d, TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with sense info MSB(sense code), next  8 bits (sense code Qual) next 8 bits (Add sense code Qual) LSB (0000) %d"            
    --#TYPE "Device has SMART/Predicictive failure event"                   
    --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d , TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with senseinfo %d"                  
    --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,5}                      
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                        
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                       
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                     
    --#HELPTAG 116                                 
::=  116
```

CODE

```
sed/grep/awk (something that deletes from first line to ::= xxx(a random number))
```

OUTPUT

```
                                                  
sCSISmart21 TRAP-TYPE                                     
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                
    DESCRIPTION                                                      
    "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                                  
    --#TYPE "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                          
    --#SUMMARY "ASPI: database file is corrupted"                                              
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                                                             
    --#SEVERITY WARNING                   
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                           
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                              
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                        
    --#HELPTAG 125
::=  125                

sCSISmart12 TRAP-TYPE                                                
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                        
    VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber, cycScsiTargetID, cycLun, cycVendor, cycProduct, cycSenseInfo}                                                       
    DESCRIPTION                           
    "The HostAdapter# %d, TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with sense info MSB(sense code), next  8 bits (sense code Qual) next 8 bits (Add sense code Qual) LSB (0000) %d"            
    --#TYPE "Device has SMART/Predicictive failure event"                   
    --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d , TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with senseinfo %d"                  
    --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,5}                      
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                        
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                       
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                     
    --#HELPTAG 116                                 
::=  116
```

So you see only first part of the file has been deleted.Later I can put this in a LOOP so that I delete one paragraph at a time.
**ALSO each file is separated by a blank link, So you could also tell me something that deletes from first line to the first blank line it encounters.**

Comment: Learn to format your question properly first. Look at your last post and how I formatted it, and http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: okay sorry about this. I will be sure its done properly next time.

Comment: And what is the "certain point"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
< inputfile sed '1,/::=/d' > outputfile
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `sed`'s `stdin`
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `sed`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

`sed` command breakdown:

- `1,/::=/d`: deletes all the lines between the first one and the first one matching the `::=` regex inclusive

---

Using `awk`:

```
< inputfile awk 'NR==1,/::=/ {next}; {print}' > outputfile
```

- `< inputfile`: redirects the content of `inputfile` to `sed`'s `stdin`
- `> outputfile`: redirects the content of `sed`'s `stdout` to `outputfile`

`awk` command breakdown:

- `NR==1,/::=/ {next}`: skips the record if between the first one and the first one matching the `::=` regex inclusive
- `{print}`: prints the record

---

Using Perl:

```
 < inputfile perl -0777 -pe 's/^(.*\n)*?::=.*\n//' > outputfile
```

- `-0777`: slurps the whole file at once instead of one line at the time
- `-p`: places a `while (<>) {[...]}` loop around the script and prints the processed file
- `-e`: reads the script from the arguments

Perl command breakdown:

- `s`: asserts to perform a substitution
- `/`: starts the pattern
- `^(.*\n)*?::=.*\n`: matches any character zero or more times at the start of the file greedily within the current line (i.e. the (`.`) pattern will be matched the most times as possible within the current line) and a newline, zero or more times lazily within the current file (i.e. the `(.*\n)` pattern will be matched the least times as possible within the current file) before a `::=` string, matching then any character zero or more times greedily within the current line and a newline
- `/`: stops the pattern / starts the replacement string
- `/`: stops the replacement string / starts the modifiers

Comment: You're getting good at answering these questions;) +1

Comment: Separator lines added =)

Answer (score 1):

Another `awk` version:

```
awk '/sCSISmart(12|20)\s+TRAP-TYPE/,/::=/ {print}' foo
```

- `/sCSISmart(12|20)\s+TRAP-TYPE/`

  matches `sCSISmart12 TRAP-TYPE` and `sCSISmart20 TRAP-TYPE`

  specify what you need

---

*Output*

```
sCSISmart20 TRAP-TYPE                                  
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                  
    DESCRIPTION                                          
    "Aspi: unable to read the file server hard disk might have problems"                           
    --#TYPE "Aspi: unable to read the database file"                                 
    --#SUMMARY "ASPI: unable to read the file, server hard disk may have problems"                                     
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                                 
    --#SEVERITY WARNING                                         
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                                                    
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                                          
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                                                      
    --#HELPTAG 124                         
::=  124                                                                                            
sCSISmart12 TRAP-TYPE                                                
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                        
    VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber, cycScsiTargetID, cycLun, cycVendor, cycProduct, cycSenseInfo}                                                       
    DESCRIPTION                           
    "The HostAdapter# %d, TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with sense info MSB(sense code), next  8 bits (sense code Qual) next 8 bits (Add sense code Qual) LSB (0000) %d"            
    --#TYPE "Device has SMART/Predicictive failure event"                   
    --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d , TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with senseinfo %d"                  
    --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,5}                      
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                        
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                       
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                     
    --#HELPTAG 116                                 
::=  116
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Pure BASH approach

The script below takes a file as command-line argument and prints all lines only after first `::=` string is encountered.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
main(){
    local flag=false
    while IFS= read -r line;
    do 
        case "$line" in
            *"::="*) flag=true && continue ;;
        esac
        $flag && echo "$line"
    done  < "$1"
}
main "$@"
```

Test run (agrees with OP's desired output):

```
$ ./remove_paragraph.sh  input.txt                                                                    

sCSISmart21 TRAP-TYPE                                     
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                
    DESCRIPTION                                                      
    "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                                  
    --#TYPE "Aspi: database is corrupted"                                          
    --#SUMMARY "ASPI: database file is corrupted"                                              
    --#ARGUMENTS {}                                                             
    --#SEVERITY WARNING                   
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                           
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                              
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                        
    --#HELPTAG 125

sCSISmart12 TRAP-TYPE                                                
    ENTERPRISE  cyclone                                                        
    VARIABLES {cycHostAdapterNumber, cycScsiTargetID, cycLun, cycVendor, cycProduct, cycSenseInfo}                                                       
    DESCRIPTION                           
    "The HostAdapter# %d, TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with sense info MSB(sense code), next  8 bits (sense code Qual) next 8 bits (Add sense code Qual) LSB (0000) %d"            
    --#TYPE "Device has SMART/Predicictive failure event"                   
    --#SUMMARY "The HostAdapter# %d , TargetID %d, Lun# %d has Predictive Failure Condition on vendor %s product %s with senseinfo %d"                  
    --#ARGUMENTS {0,1,2,3,4,5}                      
    --#SEVERITY INFORMATIONAL                
    --#TIMEINDEX 100                        
    --#STATE OPERATIONAL                       
    --#HELP "scsismrt.hlp"                     
    --#HELPTAG 116
```